# How to go inside docker container and launch pipenv shell with Makefile command?

Tags: docker, makefile, pipenv

My dockerized project uses pipenv to deal with python dependencies, intepreter etc. Currently I have Makefile command which with I can go inside my docker container:

```
to-container:
    docker exec -ti my_container_name bash
```

I would want this command also automatically launch pipenv shell inside the container, like that:

```
to-container:
    docker exec -ti my_container_name bash && pipenv shell
```

Is this possible, and what is the trick?

Comment: Could you post your docker file?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because it is private, but I can tell you something about it if you can specify what kind of information you would need

Comment: This doesn't really make sense (you wouldn't use `pdb` to "get inside" your running Python process, run a package-manager tool, and try to restart it; `docker exec` is the same concept).  Generally you'd build a new image with the updated packages, then delete and recreate your container based on the new image.

Comment: This is not a makefile question, this is just a docker (or really, a shell) question.  As always with makefiles you should first ensure that the command you want to run works if you run it directly from your command prompt, then once that works it's trivial to put that same command into a makefile recipe (doubling the `$`).  If you can't get it to work from the shell command line, it surely won't work from within a makefile.  If you type that command at your shell prompt, you'll see it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @DavidMaze There is good reasons behind, why I want to use pipenv inside my container, and therefore not want to build a new image with updated packages to avoid using pipenv. This was my first option, but after a long researh we found using pipenv inside container being a better solution

Comment: @MadScientist I still think this question is related to all, Makefile, Docker and shell. I can launch pipenv with my shell, even inside the docker container, but problem is to get pipenv shell running inside docker container by makefile command. I am not sure if this is possible at all, but that is the reason why I asked this question

Comment: If you can get the command you want to run to work as a single command from your shell prompt, then that same single command can be put into a makefile and it will work.  make is just running commands, similar to what your shell does.  make is not an interactive tool: it can't run one command then from within that same command run another command, etc.  It can only run commands one at a time from the "top level".

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you want like this.  Forget even docker for now, much less make.  What does this do when you invoke it:

```
bash && pipenv shell
```

First, it runs the `bash` program and waits for that program to finish.  Second, assuming that the `bash` program exits successfully, it will run `pipenv shell`.  It certainly will *not* run the `pipenv shell` command *inside* the `bash` program.

You want this, or something like it:

```
bash -c 'pipenv shell'
```

This will start a `bash` program and ask it to run the `pipenv shell` command, then (after `pipenv shell` completes) exit.  `pipenv shell` will *itself* start an interactive shell (as I understand it, I don't use `pipenv` myself).  This is a little gross since you have two shells but it's not a big deal.

To translate this into docker you'd use:

```
docker exec -ti my_container_name bash -c 'pipenv shell'
```

then to put that into your makefile:

```
to-container:
        docker exec -ti my_container_name bash -c 'pipenv shell'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helps me understanding some basics related to this problem. Unfortunately this approach not work, it gives the following error:
```pipenv.vendor.shellingham._core.ShellDetectionFailure```

If I manually run, `docker exec -ti cont_name bash` and then `pipenv shell` inside container, I am able to run pipenv shell. To get everything work by one make command seems to be more tricky. In my docker build I already noticed that I was not allowed to run subshells inside my container. (pipenv shell did not work). Instead I ran `pipenv run command`

Comment: In this case `pipenv run something` is not a preferred solution, since I would want my make command to direct the user (other developers) inside container and pipenv, to make everything work reliable and easily

Comment: Well, I don't know why  pipenv gives that error so you'll have to ask the pipenv folks why running `bash -c 'pipenv shell'` gives that error.  Maybe there's some other pipenv command that will work better.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little bit late to the party. But I stumbled onto this page just today. So for anyone who comes after. I think you might want to set `pipenv shell` in your ~/.bashrc file as that file is loaded every time you access bash.

For example, in my Dockerfile, my WORKDIR is set to /opt/app/ and my Pipfile is under the same directory. Thus, I just need to add `pipenv shell` at the end of my .bashrc file. And Voila! running `bash exec -ti container-name /bin/bash` will go straight to pipenv environment.